# Cross-page postback: Prevent Response.Redirect() being called from within PreviousPage

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create a search form for an internal web application, which will appear on most pages. I put the search form into an ascx user control (SearchPanel.ascx), and configured the Search button with PostBackUrl="Default.aspx". I've also created a public event handler on the user control, which fires when the Search button is clicked (so that I can handle searches that are initiated directly from Default.aspx).

Searching while viewing Default.aspx works fine, via the event handler in SearchPanel.ascx. When I try to search from a different page hosting the user control, the browser posts to Default.aspx, but this.PreviousPage is null. Thus I can't check for IsCrossPagePostBack, nor can I use PreviousPage.FindControl("Search") to access the public properties of the search form (text and a couple of checkboxes).

Is there something else I have to do in order to handle a cross-page postback initiated from a user control?

**Update:**

If I break the debugger during Page_Load and examine the Request.Form collection, I can see the form values being passed from the original page, along with a __PREVIOUSPAGE value that seems to be encrypted/encoded like ViewState.

When I step through Page_Load with the debugger, the results are rather weird. If I step-into on the line where it checks if PreviousPage != null, I can see it instantiating the page where the request came from. Once it's finished, it returns to the beginning of Page_Load in Default.aspx, and runs it again. This time, PreviousPage is simply null.

I must be doing something stupid, but so far I don't know what it is.

**The Plot Thickens:**

Okay, the User Control detail turned out to be a bit of a red herring. The Details.aspx page accepts a query string parameter indicating which item to show. If that parameter is blank, it redirects back to Default.aspx. It appears what's happening is Default.aspx receives the cross-page postback, and when it checks PreviousPage, the Page_Load() method of Details.aspx is run.

However, it looks like the query string parameter isn't sent back to Details.aspx, so it hits this error checking code and runs the Response.Redirect() error handler.

It appears what I need to do is have Details.aspx check whether it's being executed as PreviousPage in a cross-page post-back, and skip most of the execution that it would normally do. How can I check for that condition? Page.IsPostBack doesn't seem to be catching it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I just had to check for Page.IsCrossPagePostBack within the Page_Load() of Details.aspx, and then skip a bunch of initialization if it's true.

Then there's the matter of trying to use Page.PreviousPage.FindControl() when PreviousPage happens to be a content page nested in 2 or 3 layers of master pages... Obviously, I just settled for shuffling things around in HttpContext.Current.Items.